# Skip Double Comma in Split Function

Tags: ms-access, vba

My String (strSQL) Value is 1,2,3,,4 and My result shows blank between 3 and 4 due to Double comma (,,). My Code is Following:-

```
strParts = Split(strSQL, ", ")
        For intCounter = LBound(strParts()) To UBound(strParts())
            Me.Controls("cmd" & intCounter).Visible = True
            Me.Controls("cmd" & intCounter).Caption = strParts(intCounter)                
        Next intCounter
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace a double (`,,`) by a single one (`,`) before splitting:

```vba
strSQL = Replace(strSQL, ",,", ",")
```

Or you use a separate index:

```vba
strParts = Split(strSQL, ",")

Dim index As Long
Dim counter As Long
For index = LBound(strParts()) To UBound(strParts())
    If Len(Trim(strParts(index))) > 1 Then
        counter = counter + 1
        Me.Controls("cmd" & counter).Visible = True
        Me.Controls("cmd" & counter).Caption = strParts(index)
    End If
Next index
```

Answer (score 1):

As you also could have tripled commas, just ignore the empty entries:

```
Dim Part As String

strParts = Split(strSQL, ",")

For intCounter = LBound(strParts()) To UBound(strParts())
    Part = Trim(strParts(intCounter))
    If Part <> "" Then
        Me.Controls("cmd" & Part).Visible = True
        Me.Controls("cmd" & Part).Caption = Part
    Else
        Me.Controls("cmd" & Part).Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to "sanitize" your string to remove extra commas before splitting. However, as @Gustaf notes, you could have more than 2 commas in a row. So a possible solution is to iteratively remove extra commas until you don't have any. Such a function looks like this:

```
' given a string that contains consecutive commas (e.g. abc,,def,,,ghi),
' removes all but the first commas (e.g. abc,def,ghi
Public Function RemoveDuplicateCommas(ByVal s As String) As String
    Do While InStr(1, s, ",,", vbBinaryCompare) > 0
        s = Replace(s, ",,", ",")
    Loop

    RemoveDuplicateCommas = s
End Function
```

To use this function, do something like this:

```
strSQL = "1,2,3,,4,,,5"
strSQL = RemoveDuplicateCommas(strSQL)
?strSQL
1,2,3,4,5
?join(split(strsql, ","), ",")
1,2,3,4,5
```